# The post data itself is converted to raw

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, axios

When sending a post request in React Native from Android via axios, the data is sent to the server in the format raw.

RN 0.67.3
axios 0.26.0

Server% php 7.1

What could be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

I have 2 ideas about this problem but as you did not add any code to your question I am not certain about my answer:

1. Compare your Axios post with this full example of post in Axios and use "Content-Type': 'application/json":

```
var postData = {
  email: "test@test.com",
  password: "password"
};

let axiosConfig = {
  headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
  }
};

axios.post('http://<host>:<port>/<path>', postData, axiosConfig)
.then((res) => {
  console.log("RESPONSE RECEIVED: ", res);
})
.catch((err) => {
  console.log("AXIOS ERROR: ", err);
})
```

2. Make sure that is your path secure (https) in android if you want to send data over http you have too edit the AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<manifest 
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

        <application
           android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"> 

                // ----------------

        </application>
   </manifest>
```